# maven gmavenplus-plugin problems with groovy syntax

Tags: maven, groovy

I am trying to customize maven build process using `gmavenplus-plugin`.
To be precise, I have a workig script in `gmaven-plugin` and I am trying to re-implement it in `gmavenplus-plugin`(which is advertised as a rewrite of GMaven)

My running gmaven code

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                    println(project.version)
                    println([1, 2, 3])
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My attempt to re-write it in gmavenplus:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <scripts>
            println(project.version)
            println([1, 2, 3])
        </scripts>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Which fails with

```
[ERROR] Script1.groovy: 2: unexpected token: 1 @ line 2, column 34.
[ERROR] println([1
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1 error
```

Any groovy syntax I try to use fails.

**Update**
CDATA does not help.

```
<scripts>
<![CDATA[
println(project.version)
println([1, 2, 3])
]]>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the code in `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` as shown [in the examples](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki/Examples#execute-scripts)?

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, I tried CDATA. I also tried 3.0.0-beta-1 version of groovy (in fact I first tried to run on Java 12, and I only managed to run it with this update)

Comment: according to examples https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki/Examples there should be `<scripts><script>...`

Comment: @daggett You nailed it. Time to get some sleep :/ I will be happy to accept your coment as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to examples https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki/Examples

there should be `<script>` inside `<scripts>`:

use `mvn gplus:execute` with the following example `pom.xml`

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test-gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-gmavenplus</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test gmavenplus</name>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      <configuration>
        <scripts>
          <script><![CDATA[
            println "hello `${project.name}`"
          ]]></script>
        </scripts>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.7</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```